# How to make website scrollable without seeing scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the scrollbar of the browser and still be able to scroll.

I have tried:
`overflow: hidden;` in the parent div
`overflow-y: auto;` in child div

I expected it to hide scrollbars and scroll as normal, but it removed the browser scroll bars and added one by itself, which wouldn't let me move.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("image");
  background-attachment: scroll;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*other css is inline at the top 2 divs*/
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden">
  <div style="overflow-y: scroll; padding-right: 10px">

    <p style="font-weight: 800; font-size: 60px; font-family:sans-serif; text-align: center; color: #ff4e00; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 3px solid #ff4e00;">Burgers</p>
    <a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px">
      <div style="position:absolute; border: solid black auto; background: white; border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 30px;" class="menuTemplate">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702-sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg" height="250px" width="335" style="padding: 10px" ::after>
        </div>
        <div class="menuTextBox">VEG TREAT BURGER</div>
        <div class="menuInfo">
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inner">Price:</span></div>
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inner">45₹</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>


    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <p style="font-weight: 800; font-size: 60px; font-family:sans-serif; text-align: center; color: #ff4e00; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 3px solid #ff4e00;">Burgers</p>
    <a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px">
      <div style="position:absolute; border: solid black auto; background: white; border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;" class="menuTemplate">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702-sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg" height="250px" width="335" style="padding: 10px" ::after>
        </div>
        <div class="menuTextBox">VEG TREAT BURGER</div>
        <div class="menuInfo">
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inner">Price:</span></div>
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inners">45₹</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/close-up-burger-with-black-background_23-2148234990.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*other overflows are inline at the top
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden">
  <div style="overflow-y: scroll; padding-right: 10px">

    <p style="font-weight: 800; font-size: 60px; font-family:sans-serif; text-align: center; color: #ff4e00; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 3px solid #ff4e00;">Burgers</p>
    <a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px">
      <div style="position:absolute; border: solid black auto; background: white; border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 30px;" class="menuTemplate">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702-sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg" height="250px" width="335" style="padding: 10px" ::after>
        </div>
        <div class="menuTextBox">VEG TREAT BURGER</div>
        <div class="menuInfo">
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inner">Price:</span></div>
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inner">45₹</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>


    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <p style="font-weight: 800; font-size: 60px; font-family:sans-serif; text-align: center; color: #ff4e00; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 3px solid #ff4e00;">Burgers</p>
    <a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px">
      <div style="position:absolute; border: solid black auto; background: white; border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;" class="menuTemplate">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702-sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg" height="250px" width="335" style="padding: 10px" ::after>
        </div>
        <div class="menuTextBox">VEG TREAT BURGER</div>
        <div class="menuInfo">
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inner">Price:</span></div>
          <div><span class="menuInfo-inners">45₹</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the scrollbar use -webkit- because it is supported by major browsers (Google Chrome, Safari or newer versions of Opera). There are many other options for the other browsers which are listed below:

--webkit- (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera):
`.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }`
--moz- (Firefox):
`.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }`
--ms- (Internet Explorer +10):
`.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your page content into a wrapper element ( div in my case here ) and add the CSS below to your app.

I have here a working example: https://2xtlr.csb.app/

**CSS:**

```
body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page {
   max-height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   margin: 0 -15px 0 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
     <div class="page">
         ... <!-- YOUR PAGE CONTENT GOES HERE -->
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did try but still didnt work. i have tried putting all the page inside a div and doing the same. but seems to not work so i used the other method of webkits or elements
still thanks for your reply.